# Dagger 2 issue:@Subcomponent.Builder methods that have no arguments must return the @Subcomponent type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm having a subcomponent module using dagger 2.

```
@Subcomponent(modules = arrayOf(LoginPageActivityModule::class))
class AuthModule {

    @Provides
    internal fun provideAuthDataManager(appDataManager: AppDataManagerImpl): AuthRepository {
        return AuthRepository(appDataManager)
    }

    @Subcomponent.Builder
    internal interface Builder {
        fun requestModule(module: AuthModule): Builder
        fun build(): AppComponent
    }
}
```

I want to add it inside another module -

```
@Module(subcomponents = arrayOf(AuthModule::class))
    class LoginPageActivityModule {

@Provides
    internal fun provideLoginPageViewModel(dataManager: LoginRepository,authDataManager: AuthRepository): LoginPageViewModel {
        return LoginPageViewModel(dataManager,authDataManager)
    }

  }
```

When I do this, Im getting this issue -

> @Subcomponent.Builder methods that have no arguments must return the
>   @Subcomponent type or a supertype of the @Subcomponent  public
>   abstract com.lola.AppComponent build();

How do I delclare a Factory or Builder ?

Comment: You declare a `@SubComponent AuthModule` with a builder that returns `AppComponent` and Dagger complains about your builder not returning the subcomponents type... which would probably be `AuthModule` in this case

Comment: @DavidMedenjak .. Im finding it bit confusing, can you show how the code looks like ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return `AuthModule` as that is the name of your component.

Though I imagine you've mistyped some names there, possibly you wanted to call that component `AppComponent`. (Calling a Component with a name ending in -module is super confusing)